# Removing application in WSO2 ESB does not remove components

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I managed to deploy my car that contains various apis, sequences, ... and to deploy it trhough the maven plugin.

Unfortunately, when I try to undeploy it (Carbon Applications > Delete), everything seems to work fine:

```
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  
Successfully Undeployed Carbon Application : distribution_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT {super-tenant} 
{org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager}
```

but it does not delete anything.

The list of APIs still contains my definitions:

[image]

After I restart the server, the components are removed.

Is there something I have to flush, a cache, or anything else to "commit" the deletion ?

Thanks in advance

- WSO2 ESB 5.0.0
- Ubuntu 16.04
- JDK 1.8 Oracle

Comment: AFAIK there is no commit or flush kind of thing needed. Have you tried refreshing the page after deletion?.

Comment: Of course :) Currently, I need to reload the whole server ... :-/

Comment: same thing happening with me as well. Only reload can help

Comment: @SureshDhaka take a look to my answer, maybe the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the ESB was not removing the car because the name of the artifact was 'abc' when the name of components was 'xyz'.

It is important that the name of your components is exactly the same that the name of the artifacts in your CAR. In the exampel bellow, the name is always 'heart-beat', in the `component`, the  `artifacts.xml` and in the `pom.xml`

The component:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="heart-beat" 
     context="/heart-beat">
   <resource methods="GET">
     ...
   </resource>
</api>
```

The artifacts.xml

```
<artifact name="heart-beat" groupId="..." version="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
          type="synapse/api" serverRole="EnterpriseServiceBus">
```

The pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>heart-beat</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>xml</type>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have to do anything rather than deleting capp.

You do below steps to investigate more.

1) Once capp deleted, it shows which artifacts are undeployed along with "pplicationManager Successfully Undeployed Carbon Application" logs. Check weather all your artifacts are listed there

```
[2016-09-21 23:08:44,630]  INFO - SequenceDeployer Sequence named 'callGetMemberStatementESB' has been undeployed
[2016-09-21 23:08:44,630]  INFO - SequenceDeployer Sequence named 'getMemberStatement' has been undeployed
[2016-09-21 23:08:44,631]  INFO - SequenceDeployer Sequence named 'getMemberTransactions' has been undeployed
[2016-09-21 23:08:44,632]  INFO - ApplicationManager Successfully Undeployed Carbon Application : GetMemberStatement_1.0.0 {super-tenant}
```

2) Check trying to accessing proxy or api if it is still showing just to check if api is undeployed. Sometime it may be browser cache.

If this is consistent and you think it is a bug, please create a ticket in WSO2 public jira.

Answer (score 0):

You will need go to source view and remove API from the code. Then it will destroy the API from ESB.

Service Bus => Source View => Remove appropriate API and update it